# Ubuntu 14.04 Login loop

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, ubuntu-14.04, gnome-shell

I am facing an infinite login loop issue: the login screen is appearing again and again after accepting correct credentials. Still, I can access the virtual terminal by using Ctrl+Alt+F1 /Ctrl+Alt+F3.

I played around .XAuthority, .ICEauthority, file permissions, backups and removals of these files, purge and reInstallations of lightDM and gDM.

I'm still facing the same issue. Below are errors I am able to see in .xsession-errors file:

```
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (11515) terminated with status 1
init: logrotate main process (11404) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_nm-applet.104.crash) main process (11451) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-bluetooth main process (11638) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-power main process (11640) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-datetime main process (11641) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-session main process (11655) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-application main process (11671) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
```

I am not interested in upgrading it as the current configuration is matched to existing project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I have added export `$PATH="~/bin" as last line in ~/.bash_profile.`

I **solved** it by removing the line after entering into `tty2` command line using `"ctrl + alt + F3"` and all commands like `"ls, cd, nano"` where available as `"/bin/ls, /bin/cd, /bin/nano"`.

Using command "/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile" I changed the file content and now it's working normally.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04: 
One workaround you can think of is, set `auto-login` for your user.

1. Add below lines to your */etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf* file

   ```
   [SeatDefaults]
   autologin-guest=false
   autologin-user=oli
   autologin-user-timeout=0
   autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
   greeter-session=
   user-session=ubuntu
   ```
2. Restart lightdm service by

   ```
   service lightdm restart
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (I'm using fedora 28). I ran yum update but probably some problem happened during the process. When I turned on my computer couldn't login anymore. Screen blinked once switching into graphic and terminal e switch back to login.

I solved my problem going to terminal (CTRL + ALT + F2), loging and reinstalling gnome

```
sudo yum install @gnome-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you weren't interested in upgrading, but as there weren't many S/O questions with this particular setup, I figured I'd answer just in case someone else IS interested in upgrading.

For me, the answer was to upgrade my linux kernel:

```
mkdir kernel-4.16.0
cd kernel-4.16.0
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16/linux-headers-4.16.0-041600_4.16.0-041600.201804012230_all.deb
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16/linux-headers-4.16.0-041600-generic_4.16.0-041600.201804012230_amd64.deb
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16/linux-image-4.16.0-041600-generic_4.16.0-041600.201804012230_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your PATH variable inside your /etc/environment then undo the changes this will also cause login loop.
Paste the PATH varible as PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/bin/usr/games:/usr/local/games" save and try login again